# JPype conflicts with django and raven

Tags: django, sentry, raven, jpype

I am using jpype 0.6.1. I have written a python script to run some piece of code written in scala. Every thing is working as expected. But when I have integrated python script into my django project, I was getting some errors related to raven module.

Scala code to print message :

```
package com.test.auth

object Auth {
  // returns the message passed as parameter
  def printMessage(message: String) : String = {
    message
  }
}
```

Python script that accesses above code

```
import jpype
from jpype import *

classpath = '-Djava.class.path=/home/ec2-user/dt/jars/Auth.jar'

jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(),classpath)
authPackage = JPackage('com.test.auth')
Auth = authPackage.Auth
msg = Auth.printMessage("Hello World")
print "message : ",msg
```

The above code is working fine. but after integrating into django project, I was getting following error

> TypeError: Package com.test.auth.Auth.printMessage.__sentry__ is not
>   Callable 2016-08-16 07:56:08,850 [ERROR]
>   logger=sentry.errors.serializer process=14605 thread=140040558467072
>   Package com.test.auth.Auth.printMessage.__sentry__ is not Callable

I am new to django. I have read about the raven logging mechanism. but unable to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into this, we're just logging this and this should not interfere with Raven's normal reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I had just the same problem. I manage fix this after putting on the Django project root folder the folder with all .class files that i was using.